# Is it possible to stop my labels disappearing on my flex pie chart between segment selections whilst interpolating?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, label, interpolation, pie-chart

I have a flex pie chart:

```
    <mx:PieChart alpha="0.9" fontSize="{QPieSeries_font}" width="100%" top="20" height="320" id="QPieChart" 
                 dataProvider="{dataObj}" horizontalCenter="0" color="0xFFFFFF" fontFamily="MyriadWebPro" 
                 showDataTips="true" dataTipFunction="QdataTipFunction" 
                 dataTipItemsSet="true" itemClick="QPieChart_itemClickHandler(event)">
        <mx:series>
            <mx:PieSeries id="QPieSeries" labelField="Answer" field="Value" labelPosition="callout"
                          showDataEffect="QSeriesInterpolate" alpha="1"
                          reserveExplodeRadius="0.05"/>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:PieChart>
```

where the `QSeriesInterpolate` is a simple interpolation given in the declaration:

```
<fx:Declarations>       
    <mx:SeriesInterpolate id="QSeriesInterpolate" duration="500" />
</fx:Declarations>
```

and the item click event looks like:

```
protected function QPieChart_itemClickHandler(event:ChartItemEvent):void
        {
                var ExAr:Array = [];
                ExAr[event.hitData.chartItem.index] = 0.05;
                QPieSeries.perWedgeExplodeRadius = ExAr;
        }
```

Basically, what annoys me is that when I click a segment to activate the interpolated event, the datatips disappear for it's duration. Whilst this is only half a second, it still detracts from user experience. Is there anything I can do to avoid it??

ALSO! Another thing: Is it obvious to anyone why my dataTipFunction doesnt work? It looks as follows:

```
            public function QdataTipFunction(hitData:HitData):String
        {
            var a:String = "abc"
            return a;
        }
```

Yes it's simple but I was just trying to persuade it to work... to no avail. I think it might be some sort of font issue?

Thanks!

Josh

Comment: Yea I really haven't provided any detail as to why I think it's a font issue. Originally the labels wouldn't appear, as a result of me defining a global font in the top CSS file, but this was fixed by defining the font of the PieChart. However this same fix does not solve this problem for the data tips. Perhaps it's not a font issue, idk... I'd just really like it to work. Thanks again.

Comment: its not a font issue, im having the same problem, and i havent used any custom fonts in my application. I am guessing this is a limitation of the Flex charting component - there is simply no animation available for the labels. To solve this one would need to dig in deeply into the charting components, which are super complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider looking into Axiis.  It is a flex data visualization framework, and has some awesome example charts.  The main deal though is you have full control over EVERTHING! Probably overkill for what you are doing, but it really is awesome.

http://www.axiis.org/examples.html